# Using binomial theorem to express $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \ [((\sqrt{5}/2)+(1/2))^{10} - (-(\sqrt{5}/2)+(1/2))^{10}]$ as a single finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am trying to write
$$\frac1{\sqrt5}\left[(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}
- (-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}\right]
$$
as a single finite series of the form $\sum^{10}_{j=0}a_j$, where $a_j$ depends on $j$.

So far I have expanded the term $(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}$ and the term $(-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}$ using the binomial theorem.

For the term  $(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}$, I got $\sum^{10}_{j=0}\binom{10}{m}(\frac12)^m(\frac{\sqrt5}2)^{10-m}$.

For the term $(-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}$, I got $\sum^{10}_{j=0}\binom{10}{m}(\frac12)^m(-\frac{\sqrt5}2)^{10-m}$.

I am not sure how to combine the terms to write them under one series.

This is what I have written so far:
$$\frac1{\sqrt5}\left[(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}
- (-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}\right]
$$

$=$$\sum^{10}_{j=0}\binom{10}{m}(\frac12)^m(\frac{\sqrt5}2)^{10-m}$$ - $ $\sum^{10}_{j=0}\binom{10}{m}(\frac12)^m(-\frac{\sqrt5}2)^{10-m}$

$=$ $\sum _{m=0}^{10}\binom{10}{m}\:\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10-m}-\left(\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10-m}\right)\right)$

$=\sum _{m=0}^{10}\binom{10}{m}\:\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10-m}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m-\left(\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m\right)\right)$

The goal of the excersise is to show that $\sum^{10}_{j=0}a_j$ will give the same terms as $\frac1{\sqrt5} = \left[(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10} - (-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}\right]\\$

which will give same terms as
$\sum^5_{j=1}\binom{10}{ 2j-1}\frac{5^{j-1}}{2^9}
$

So I need help in writting  $\sum^{10}_{j=0}a_j$, and so far I have  $\sum^{10}_{j=0}a_j$

$=\sum _{m=0}^{10}\binom{10}{m}\:\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10-m}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m-\left(\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m\right)\right)$

The goal of the final exercise is to show that these terms yield the same terms as the series $\sum^5_{j=1}\binom{10}{2j-1}\frac{5^{j-1}}{2^9}$. Or in other words, show that

$$\frac1{\sqrt5}
\left[(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10} - (-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12)^{10}\right]\\
= \sum^5_{j=1}\binom{10}{ 2j-1}\frac{5^{j-1}}{2^9}
$$

To do so, I need help in combining the expansion of the terms under one series in the form $\sum^{10}_{j=0} a_j$, where $a_j$ depends on $j$.

I mainly need someone to check if $\sum^{10}_{j=0}a_j$ $=\sum _{m=0}^{10}\binom{10}{m}\:\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10-m}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m-\left(\left(-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^m\right)\right)$ is correct or not. I can expand the terms myself and I know that they cancel out. I am also not supposed to use any calculator computations, so I am not looking for the sum of the series, just the series itself.

Thank you for any solutions and answers or any sort of help provided.

Comment: Since you are taking a difference, some terms will cancel.  What terms are _the same_ in $ \  (a + b)^{10} \ $ and $ \  (a - b)^{10} \ $  ?  [Don't insert the values first.]  What can you say about the remaining terms?

Comment: so I should cancel out the terms  that are the same first?

Comment: Please fix your MathJax. `\sqrt{a}` to get $\sqrt{a}$, not `sqrt(a)`.

Comment: That will save a lot of work, as slightly more than half of the original terms will cancel.  You should also notice something about the exponents of $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ in the remaining terms.

Comment: @boojum after I cancel out the terms, how do I write it all under one series?

Comment: Is there a pattern among the five binomial series terms that remain?  How can they be related to the summation you are being asked to demonstrate?  Once you insert $ \ a \ = \ \frac12 \ $ and $ \ b \ = \ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \ ,  $ you should see some of the other parts of the final expression.

Comment: `$\sum_{a}^{b}$` gives $\sum_{a}^{b}$ while `$\binom{n}{k}$` gives $\binom{n}{k}$

Comment: Uhm, this is just Binet's formula for $F_{10}=55$...
I mean, with this you could simply write $\sum_{j=0}^{10}j$.

Comment: @AnayAggarwal: Except that the problem is an exercise in manipulating the expression into a specific form.

Comment: @AnayAggarwal Thanks for mentioning that, I thought it was Binet's formula but I wasn't sure completely. Unfortunately, I can't simply write is as Binet's formula, the exercise asks me to show it by using the steps that I am stuck on as mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not so bad if you do the simplifications in a better order:

$$\begin{align*}
&\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12\right)^{10}-\left(-\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12\right)^{10}\right)\\
&\qquad=\frac1{2^{10}\sqrt5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k5^{k/2}-\sum_{k=0}^{10}(-1)^k\binom{10}k5^{k/2}\right)\\
&\qquad=\frac1{2^{10}\sqrt5}\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k5^{k/2}\left(1-(-1)^k\right)\\
&\qquad=\frac1{2^9\sqrt5}\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{10}{2k-1}5^{k+\frac12}\\
&\qquad=\frac1{2^9}\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{10}{2k+1}5^k\\
&\qquad=\frac1{2^9}\sum_{k=1}^5\binom{10}{2k-1}5^{k-1}
\end{align*}$$

The first step factors out the denominator and applies the binomial theorem to $\left(\sqrt5+1\right)^{10}$ and $\left(-\sqrt5+1\right)^{10}$; the third recognizes that the terms with even $k$ cancel out and keeps only the terms with odd $k$; and the last simply shifts the index by $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you explain to me how you got to the 1st and 2nd equations a bit more. I am mostly confused about the 1st step.

Comment: @charles: $$\left(\frac{\sqrt5}2+\frac12\right)^{10}=\frac1{2^{10}}\left(\sqrt5+1\right)^{10}\,,$$ and the binomial theorem says that $$\left(\sqrt5+1\right)^{10}=\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k\left(\sqrt5\right)^k(1)^{10-k}\,,$$ which simplifies to $\sum_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k5^{k/2}$. The other term is the same idea, but with $\left(-\sqrt5+1\right)^{10}$.

Comment: Thanks! Also, how did you shift the index and get to $4$ from $10$?

Comment: @charles: You mean from an upper limit of $4$ to an upper limit of $5$ in the last step? Make a substitution: let $\ell=k+1$. Then as $k$ runs from $0$ up through $4$, $\ell$ runs from $1$ up through $5$. And $k=\ell-1$, so $2k+1=2(\ell-1)+1=2\ell-1$, and $$\sum_{k=0}^4\binom{10}{2k+1}5^k5^k=\sum_{\ell=1}^5\binom{10}{2\ell-1}5^{\ell-1}\,.$$ Now just rename $\ell$ to $k$.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @charles: You’re very welcome.